# Change IP Address and fill in captcha code using imacros in loop

Tags: loops, ip, captcha, imacros, advanced-search

Hi i was wondering if anybody of you guys could help me out with exampel of how a similir code would look like, Im intressted of by using imacros to visit a site and do a search for example "hawaii" and then enter a captcha code and press enter and then extract all info about hawaii registred on this site and after that change my ip number and making a loop of it with a new search?

Or is this even possible? 
Heheh, thankfull for all feedback!

Comment: Yes it is but this is not something simple to make. It has to use javascript scripting and loading from file with ip addresses.

Comment: could u perhaps link me a tutorial or atleast maybe just show me a example of how it would look like ..

Comment: Here you can find a lot of answers about iMacros and JavaScript. Do a little research and make something. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1452141/macroscripts?tab=answers

Comment: Did u solve it ? Im intrested of a similiar solution